# How to mock "connect" in paramiko SSHClient() using pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, paramiko

My util class is something like this.

```
class SSHUtils(object):
    def __init__(self, host, user=None, pwd=None):
        try:
            self.host = host
            logging.info(" Creating SSH session - %s, user name - %s & pswd - %s ", host, user, pwd)
            self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            if user and pwd:
                self.ssh.connect(host, 22, user, pwd, timeout=10)
            else:
                self.ssh.connect(host, 22, timeout=10)

            transport = self.ssh.get_transport()
            transport.set_keepalive(30)
            channel = self.ssh.invoke_shell()  # nosec

            self.stdin = channel.makefile('wb')
            self.stdout = channel.makefile('r')

            logging.info(" Created SSH session - %s", host)
        except Exception as error:
            logging.error("Failed to create SSH sesssion to server - %s, %s", host, error)
            raise Exception("Failed to create SSH sesssion to server - " + host + " exception - " + str(error))

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            logging.info(" Delete SSH session - %s", self.host)
            self.ssh.close()
        except Exception as error:
            logging.info(" Exception while Delete SSH session - %s", self.host)
```

I tried to mock this class using this fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture
def get_util_client(*args, **kwargs):
    ssh = SSHUtils("130b:tde9:5043:5000::4", "b", "c")
    return ssh
```

But when I trying to use this in my test fuction, I'm having bellow error.

```
Exception: Failed to create SSH sesssion to server - 130b:tde9:5043:5000::4 exception - [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 22 on 130b:tde9:5043:5000::4
```

My question is How can I mock SSHUtils class in pytest?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there is no mocking happening in `get_util_client` as you are just instantiating the actual `SSHUtils` object. You will need to use either `pytest-mock` or python's builtin `mock` module (`mock.patch` decorator or method).

Also may be the mocking needs to happen at a higher level class that uses `SSHUtils` as it's component, as it looks like `SSHUtils` is an implementation class ?

Relevant links:

[Python's builtin mock module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch)

[pytest module's mock wrapper](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock/)